# Uses for the Java Void Reference Type?

Tags: java, void

There is a Java `Void` -- uppercase V-- [reference type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html). The only situation I have ever seen it used is to parameterize `Callable`s

```
final Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() {
                foobar();
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Are there any other uses for the Java `Void` reference type? Can it ever be assigned anything other than `null`? If yes, do you have examples?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-void-class-exist-jdk

Comment: In Java8, it has new functions: [use Function interface to replace Consumer or Supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369776/java8-use-function-interface-to-replace-consumer-or-supplier)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`Void` has become convention for a generic argument that you are not interested in. There is no reason why you should use any other non-instantiable type, such as `System`.

It is also often used in for example `Map` values (although `Collections.newSetFromMap` uses `Boolean` as maps don't have to accept `null` values) and `java.security.PrivilegedAction`.

Comment: who made that convention?  the docs state http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html  "Type Parameter Naming Conventions   By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters."

Comment: @barlop It's the argument not the parameter name. That is, it is the type `java.lang.Void`. / Josh Bloch popularised the convention, though once you've seen it, it is the obvious choice.

Comment: That blog entry is dead

Answer (score 58):

You can create instance of Void using reflections, but they are not useful for anything.  Void is a way to indicate a generic method returns nothing.

```
Constructor<Void> constructor = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Void v = constructor.newInstance();
System.out.println("I have a " + v);
```

prints something like

```
I have a java.lang.Void@75636731
```

Comment: +1 for instantiating a class that the documentation says is uninstantiable.  I've done this too and I agree that instantiated Voids are useless.

Comment: Constructor<Void> cv = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor(); cv.setAccessible(true); Void v = cv.newInstance(); System.out.println(v); // ;)

Comment: As an exercise, try creating a new Class using reflections and see what happens.

Comment: I got a java.lang.InstantiationException from sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl . :(

Comment: The only way I know of is to access defineClass of ClassLoader, but this requires providing the byte code you want to load. 8-)

Comment: This is implementation specific and may change at any time. There's no guarantee that the class has a no-arg constructor and even if it does have one that may do anything (perhaps `System.exit(0)`). I tend to write utility classes with a constructor as `private Void() { throw new Error(); }`. Some may prefer a no-value enum.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you should set the flag isAccessible to true before invoking the constructor.

Comment: @Snicolas: I did.  However, you can't do this by calling `setAccessible` on the constructor as the `AccessibleObject.setAccessible` method explicitly checks you're not trying to make the `Class` constructor accessible and throws a SecurityException if you are.  You have to make the `override` field in `AccessibleObject` accessible and then set that to `true` in order to make the `Class` constructor accessible.  The exception I mentioned is what you get if you try to call the Class constructor once you have made it accessible.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Perhaps this is JVM dependant because on HotSpot Java 7 I get the results above.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, how you then define the function for the v object?

Comment: @Luckylukee you could create your own version of the class but generally you shouldn't alter built in classes.

Answer (score 28):

[`Future<Void>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) works like charm. :)

Comment: It's more common (for example, in Guava) to use `Future<?>`, as the future will often have a legitimate value (of non-`Void` type) but is used in a context that doesn't care about the value.

Comment: [`CompletableFuture<Void>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) works like a charm as well.

Answer (score 20):

Given that there are [no public constructors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html), I would say it can't be assigned anything other than `null`. I've only used it as a placeholder for "I don't need to use this generic parameter," as your example shows.

It could also be used in reflection, from what its [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) says:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Comment: Funny enough to see Oracle/Sun describe it that way as null is an instance of all types. Anyhow, as you said, the pure meaning of it is "I could write any type here as I am not interested in it, so I will put Void to make sure people who read my code understand exactly that"

Answer (score 20):

All the primitive wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Byte`, `Boolean`, `Double`, etc.) contain a reference to the corresponding primitive class in a static `TYPE` field, for example:

```
Integer.TYPE == int.class
Byte.TYPE == byte.class
Boolean.TYPE == boolean.class
Double.TYPE == double.class
```

`Void` was initially created as somewhere to put a reference to the `void` type:

```
Void.TYPE == void.class
```

However, you don't really gain anything by using `Void.TYPE`. When you use `void.class` it's much clearer that you're doing something with the `void` type.

As an aside, the last time I tried it, [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) didn't recognise `void.class`, so you have to use `Void.TYPE` there.

Comment: So there's both a Void.class and a void.class!

Answer (score 11):

When you use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) it can be cleaner to use Void instead of Object when you want to be sure that the return value will be null

Example

```
public interface LeavesVisitor<OUT>
{
   OUT visit(Leaf1 leaf);

   OUT visit(Leaf2 leaf);
}
```

When you will implement your visitor you can explicitly set OUT to be Void so that you know your visitor will always return null, instead of using Object

```
public class MyVoidVisitor implements LeavesVisitor<Void>
{
    Void visit(Leaf1 leaf){
        //...do what you want on your leaf
        return null;
    }

    Void visit(Leaf2 leaf){
        //...do what you want on your leaf
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Before generics, it was created for the reflection API, to hold TYPE returned by Method.getReturnType() for a void method, corresponding to the other primitive type classes.

EDIT: From the JavaDoc of Void: "The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void".  Prior to Generics, I am aware of no use other than reflection.

Comment: I don't believe this.  I don't have a 1.4 or earlier JVM in front of me now, but I believe that Method.getReturnType() has always returned void.class for a void method.

Comment: @Pour: I am saying that *before* generics, the only use I am aware of is to hold TYPE (as in Void.TYPE), which was used in reflection's Method.getReturnType() for a void method.

Comment: It somehow does not return `Void`. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248693/use-instanceof-void-in-java

Answer (score 3):

As you can't instantiate Void, you can use [Apache commons Null object](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.Null.html), so

```
Null aNullObject = ObjectUtils.Null;
Null noObjectHere = null;
```

in the first line, you have an object, so `aNullObject != null` holds, while in the second line there is no reference, so `noObjectHere == null` holds

To answer the poster's original question, the usage for this is to differentiate between "the nothing" and "nothing", which are completely different things.

PS: Say no to Null object pattern

Answer (score 2):

`Void` was created to wrap its primitive `void` type. Every primitive type has its corresponding Reference type. `Void` is used to instantiate a generic class or use of a generic method, a generic argument which you are not interested in. Here is an example...

```
public void onNewRegistration() {
    newRegistrationService.createNewUser(view.getUsername(), view.getPassword(),
            view.getInitialAmount(), view.getCurrency(), new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
          
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        eventBus.fireEvent(new NewRegistrationSuccessEvent());
      }
    });
  }
```

Here, as you can see, I don't want anything from the server that I am asking to create a new registration ,but `public interface AsyncCallback<T> { .... }` is a generic interface, so i provide `Void` since generics don't accept primitive types

Answer (score 0):

It is also commonly used on Async-IO completion callbacks when you dont have the need for an `Attachment` object. In that case you specify null to the IO operation and implement `CompletionHandler<Integer,Void>`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be rare case but once, I used `Void` in aspect classes.

This was an aspect which runs after methods that has an `@Log` annotation, and logs the method returned and some info if the method return type is not void.

```
 @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(log)", 
       returning = "returnValue", 
       argNames = "joinPoint, log, returnValue"
      )
    public void afterReturning(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final Log log,
            final Object returnValue) {

            Class<?> returnType = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature())
            .getReturnType();
           if (Void.class.isAssignableFrom (returnType)) ) {
            //Do some log
         }
}
```