# In Java, is it possible to cast to void (not Void)?

Tags: java, void

Is there anything I can put in X, to make the follow work:

```
Object o = (void) X;
```

Comment: In one word: no. And there is no reason whatsoever that you should ever attempt it, apart from the basic human curiosity that makes us test whether our tongue does indeed stick to ice-cold metal surfaces.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this? (In other words, this makes no sense to me.)

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps we could help solve the over-arching issue.

Comment: Not trying to use it. I was just curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

void is notionally a primitive. (though most would disagree it is even that I suspect) You cannot cast an object to it.

The closest you can come to this is an InvocationHandler can `return null` for a void method and a void method invoke()ed via reflection will return `null`.

Comment: about *though most would disagree*: `void.class.isPrimitive()` returns true, and that's the only thing that counts

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this discussion might be of interest:
[Uses for the Java Void Reference Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type), it covers about everything you can do with `Void` and what it's good for.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not C++.  In Java, void is not a type, it is a placeholder that means "no return value".

Comment: It's still a type, but one you can't assign except in return values

Comment: `void.class` would disagree.  Its a type which has very limited valid use. It has a wrapper type of `Void` ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can set `x = null;` if you wish though?