# Not a statement. Why not?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

When I attempted to compile the following Java program:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    static int f1() { return 10; }
    static int f2() { return 20; }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 10;
        (x <= 10) ? f1() : f2();
    }
}
```

I got the error:

```
/MyClass.java:9: error: not a statement
        (x <= 10) ? f1() : f2();
                  ^
```

Java language definition talks about statements as one of assignment, increment/decrement, method invocation or object creation. My erroneous "statement" involves method invocation and should, therefore work. In fact, if I have a single statement like:

```
f1();
```

the compiler compiles the program sans any whimper. Similarly, if I change the final line to:

```
int y = (x <= 10) ? f1() : f2();
```

then too, everything is hunky-dory.

As a final piece of info, neither C nor C++ bats an eyelid on:

```
 (x <= 10) ? f1() : f2();
```

Comment: "Involves" is not the same as "is". Your "statement" is a `?:` operator expression. An expression is not a valid statement in Java (i.e. it is none of the four you listed). What C and C++ do or don't do is not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator is used in expressions. For statements, you can use an if statement. That's how the syntax is defined. Period.

Comment: The compiler error message is ambiguous. Whether it means that I have not provided any qualified Java statement, or the operator **?:** cannot be used in a statement. I will wait for a couple of days, before accepting your answer.

Comment: @SeshadriR the message is very clear: the compiler is expecting a statement, but it has found something else.