# Ternary operation on a hashMap forbidden by 'Not a statement'

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple ternary operation on a hash map:

```
   hashMap.get(number) == 1   ?
       hashMap.remove(number) :
       hashMap.merge(number, 1, Math::subtractExact);
```

I am getting a 'Not a statement' error from my IDE. What I don't understand is where this is coming from: both calls to `remove`  and `merge` sound like statements to me.

Comment: Note that the ternary operator is **not** meant as a replacement for any if-else statement. If you do not care about the return values of the remove and merge calls, then using the ternary operator isn't the right way to go.

Comment: Very related: [Java Ternary without Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977031/java-ternary-without-assignment)

Comment: @Ivar this is actually what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @tgdavies the question you are linking is about avoiding assignment in a Ternary expression in Java. This question is indirectly asking if and why do we need them.

Comment: Incidentally I think you can do what you want like this: `m.compute(number, (k, v) -> v == null || v == 1 ? null : v - 1);`

Comment: @Blue_Elephant "This question is indirectly asking if and why do we need them" <- Because that's what the ternary operator was intended and invented for. A short syntax to assign a value depending on a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the value of the ternary operator to some variable:

```
Integer value =
    hashMap.get(number) == 1   ?
    hashMap.remove(number) :
    hashMap.merge(number, 1, Math::subtractExact);
```