# What do the 3 dots in Java generics mean?

Tags: java

for example I have a code like this: [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/2180161)

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {}      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {}

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

and what do the 3 dots in the parameter of the method do?

Comment: Undefined number of arguments of type string?

Comment: Note that varargs (variable arity arguments) have nothing to do with generics.

Comment: See also [the wikipedia article on variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Comment: Nothing to do with generics. None of the methods with the `...` explicit use generic types (thus they can be viewed simply as only using non-generic types). Make sure to classify questions appropriately.

Comment: okay thank you.  thought that because I just see them in connection with generics

Comment: hey people.. just for info, can they  be used as arrays, i mean all features including foreach??

Comment: Yes they can. The varargs essentially are an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The three dots are referred to as `varargs` and here, allow you to pass more than one string to the method like so:

```
doInBackground("hello","world");
//you can also do this:
doInBackground(new String[]{"hello","world"});
```

[Documentation on that here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Within the method `doInBackground` you can enumerate over the varargs variable, `params` like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
    System.out.println(params[i]);
}
```

So its basically an array of strings within the scope of `doInBackground`

Comment: ok. and how do I access to this strings? just like an array?

Comment: @Simon Yup. In fact, at runtime it _is_ just an array, and not even a special one. The `...` stuff is purely compile-time syntactic sugar. You can even invoke the method by passing it a `String[]` (or whatever) instead of a bunch of `String`s, as this answer shows.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler treats the three dots `...` as taking in an array of that object.  In this case `String` and `Void`.  The amount of objects you pass in is the size of the array.

Thus:

`doInBackground("Hi", "Hello", "Bye")` will create an array of `String` of length 3.

Comment: so void will generate an array of the type Object?

Comment: @Simon not `void` this is `Void` it is an object itself different that the `void` your thinking of

Comment: Okay and parameters like `Void... objects` would be the same as `Object[] objects` ?

Comment: @Simon no the `Void` class is different than the `Object` class.  Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type

Answer (score 2):

This concept is called *varargs* and explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)