# Java - Interfaces, methods need to return something?

Tags: java, interface, return-value, return-type

(1st post don't bully me :D)

My question is simple, is it imperative that a method included in an interface HAS to return some value? (int, double, String etc..)
Cause last time I checked I could not define a Void method in an interface, got compiling errors.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked this website, pretty interesting: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

Comment: Use `void` instead of `Void`

Comment: Its not mandatory. You can have a method with void return type.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type

Comment: I know, I know ^^ I used capitalized void just for emphasis :P

Comment: Case matters to Java, and changing the case from `double` to `Double` is a significant change. If you want to emphasise a word I suggest you use ` like around the word so you get `word` or * around the word so you get *word*

Comment: Oh, thank you for the tip! I was just wondering how to mark the word in gray ^^ And baaam there you are, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is simple, is it imperative that a method included in an interface HAS to return some value?

No, absolutely not.

You can declare a void method in an interface, and indeed there are plenty of standard library interfaces with such methods. [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is a fine example:

```
public interface Runnable() {
    void run();
}
```

Note that declaring that a method returns `Void` is a different matter, and *usually* a mistake. (It's primarily useful for generic methods where you're going to return a value of type `T` - for example, `Runnable` is similar to `Callable<Void>`.)

Comment: Great! :D Thank you for the quick response! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "Void" or "void"?  (Use "void"!)

Comment: I know! :D
I just capitalized it to emphasize it ^^

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski: That's a really bad idea, given that there *is* a `Void` type...