# Why does the Void class exist?

Tags: java, void

**Edit**

This is a primarily a question of why the class exists, not the usages of the class. The question [Uses for the Java Void Reference Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643906/1280997) focusses on the actual usages, where this question asks for the reasoning behind its implementation.

---

Java has a boxed class [`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) for the keyword return type `void`.

From the docs:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

The only situation I have seen this class used is with generics, such as the following:

```
interface Foo<R> {
    R foo();
}

Foo<Void> foo = new Foo<Void>(){
    @Override
    public Void foo() {
        return null; //  `return;` and `return void;` are syntax errors 
    }
}
```

An example of this is Android's [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)).

The above example seems completely pointless, as the method does **not** return `void`, it will always return `null`.

So tell me, **why does `Void` exist?**

Comment: somebody downvoted without reading the question..I think this question deserves answer

Comment: Hmm... That question didn't have any answers with actually useful examples. I guess it's just there because it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required by the Reflection API, to represent the return type of a void method, as the result of `java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType().` (Stricly speaking this is `void.class,` not `Void.class,` but the compiler coerces `void.class` to `Void.TYPE`.) It is also used in several other places as shown in the [Use page in its Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Void.html).

Answer (score 2):

Void is pseudo-type void holder

```
public static final Class<Void> TYPE = Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");
```

It is since 1.1 when there was no generics yet. When we need void.class, eg here

```
Class rt = Test1.class.getMethod("x").getReturnType();
if (rt == void.class) {
   ...
```

compiler replaces void.class with a reference to java.lang.Void.TYPE

```
  ALOAD 1
  GETSTATIC java/lang/Void.TYPE : Ljava/lang/Class;
  IF_ACMPNE
  ...
```