# Use instanceof Void in java

Tags: java, class, void, typeof

I want to use the type of void java but I can't. Here is a my code which is an aspect run after to all methods which have `@TraceLog` annotations

```
  @AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(log)", 
       returning = "returnValue", 
       argNames = "joinPoint, log, returnValue"
      )
    public void afterReturning(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final TraceLog log,
            final Object returnValue) {

            Class<?> returnType = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature())
            .getReturnType();
           //It works when comperaing with string. But I want to write it with type of
           if ("void".equals(returnType.getName()) ) {
            //Do some log
         }
}
```

As a coding rule  **Classes should not be compared by name** (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/486.html), I tried to use (`returnType instanceof Void`) but I face these two compile time errors in eclipse:

```
- Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#5-of ?> and   Void
- The type Void is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <?>
```

I wonder how can I fix it ?!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if (Void.class.isAssignableFrom (returnType)) {

}
```

Example :

```
Class<?> returnType = Void.class;
if (Void.class.isAssignableFrom (returnType)) {
  System.out.println (returnType.getName ());
}
```

would print

```
java.lang.Void
```

Comment: That might be what the asker asked for, but I think the actual problem involves lowercase-v `void` (as in the string comparison the asker was trying).  Also `Void.class.isAssignableFrom` doesn't really make sense given that Void is final -- just check equality.

Comment: In extension to Jeffrey Bosboom's comment I would like to add that given a Method object m representing a void method, the call Void.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnValue()) will return false, whereas lowercase void will return true.