# java8 - use Function interface to replace Consumer or Supplier

Tags: lambda, java-8

Since that Consumer/Supplier/Predicate/UnaryOperator is just a special case of Function, how can I replace these interfacces with Function?

T -> Function -> R

T -> Consumer -> null

null -> Supplier -> T

T -> Predicate -> boolean

T -> UnaryOperator -> T

null & boolean is just a special case for T. So I write two cases using Function to replace Predicate and UnaryOperator.

For example:

```
private static void replacePredicate() {
    Function<String, Boolean> func = x -> x.startsWith("a");
    Predicate<String> pre = x -> x.startsWith("a");

    System.out.println(func.apply("ape"));
    System.out.println(pre.test("ape"));
}

private static void replaceUnaryOperator() {
    Function<Integer, Integer> func = x -> x * 2;
    UnaryOperator<Integer> uo = x -> x * 2;

    System.out.println(func.apply(6));
    System.out.println(uo.apply(6));
}
```

But how could I use Function to replace Consumer or Suppler? For example, I want to replace Consumer, but code like `Function<String, null> func = x -> System.out.println(x);` is illegal.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated~

Comment: Why would you even do that?

Comment: I'll not use Function to replace any other functions in java.util.function when coding in production environment, because use specific function rather than Function can be more convenient. However, by finding the nature of these functions, I think I can have a better understanding of these functions and can use them better in practice. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Consumer<T>` can be viewed as a `Function<T, Void>`. A `Supplier<T>` can be viewed as a `Function<Void, T>`. You'll have to return null from your consumer written as a function, and take (and ignore) a Void as argument from your supplier written as a function.

Not sure I get the point of this, though.